# Modify column_author in WP_Comments_List_Table

Tags: customization, comments, columns, screen-columns

Is it possible to modify the values in the author column in the edit-comments.php section of the backend? A hook? I want to change the mailto field for the commenter's email to include a subject and body. I am pretty sure I found where someone had said there was a way a couple of months ago, but I cannot find it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the email part is displayed by the `WP_Comments_List::column_author()` method:

```
/* This filter is documented in wp-includes/comment-template.php */
$email = apply_filters( 'comment_email', $comment->comment_author_email, $comment );

if ( ! empty( $email ) && '@' !== $email ) {
    printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br />', esc_url( 'mailto:' . $email ), esc_html( $email ) );
}
```

so you're most likely looking for the `comment_email` filter.

**Update:**

Here's a hack to add a *subject* and *body* to the `mailto` part:

```
add_filter( 'comment_email', function( $email )
{
    // Target the edit-comments.php screen
    if( did_action( 'load-edit-comments.php' ) )
        add_filter( 'clean_url', 'wpse_258903_append_subject_and_body' );       

    return $email;
} );

function wpse_258903_append_subject_and_body( $url )
{
    // Only run once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Adjust to your needs:
    $args = [ 'subject' => 'hello', 'body' => 'world' ];

    // Only append to a mailto url
    if( 'mailto' === wp_parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME )  )
        $url .= '?' . build_query( $args );

    return esc_url( $url );
}
```

Note that this targets the first `esc_url()` after each time the `comment_email` filter is applied, on the `edit-comments.php` page.

We added a *mailto* check to make sure it's for the email part.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful, but not exactly what I need. I should have clarified. I want to add a subject and body to the mailto like so:
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?subject=My Subject&body=Can you read me now?">

The problem with using the comment_email filter, as I see it, is that it will change the displayed email to my nasty, long string.

I would love to do this with filters/hooks, but I'm starting to think that the solution is going to be javascript based

Comment: I updated the answer with a hack. Antother alternative is to remove the author column and add your own. Then javascript is another way. @lost.in.userspace

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I did not know about the clean_url filter. That opens a new door for me. Thank you for taking the time to lay out the code for me too. You are a big help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it helped @lost.in.userspace